# Generating the students results print out from a database table at a time

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a table which contains the results data of a class.I made a stored procedure that selects all table data.
Now the problem is that i need a separate report for every student and want to save all report in pdf format at a time.And i want to use a stored procedure that select all data at a time.

Comment: What is exactly the problem that you're facing?

Comment: @David-The problem is that it takes first rollno and some records from tables..."But i want one roll has their records so on rollno data is shown on one page",,or we can say one data of a student per page...

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Comment: @David-sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use section expert and in this go to details section and then paging option and there set new page after one visible record.Like that..[image: Snapshot of my answer]

Now this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the goal that you want, follow these instructions

1. Create a stored procedure which will return the data for a student based on a parameter, lets say the student's ID. If you will need help on creating a parameterized stored procedure, check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_KD1P9BzQ8
2. Create a report for a student by using the stored procedure that you created. This report will display the data for a student based on a provided parameter.
3. On the C# form, add a crystalReportViewer (if you want to export directly to the PDF file, just omit the viewer), a button and a textBox. The textBox will be used for the student's selection and the button will be used for the PDF creation and exporting.
4. Inside the C# form add the following code

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       CrystalReport1 report1 = new CrystalReport1();

       report1.SetDatabaseLogon("Username","Password");
       report1.SetParameterValue("Parametername", textBox1.Text);
       report1.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "Student" + textBox1.Text + ".pdf");

       crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report1; //Remove this if you don't want a viewer.
   }
   ```

   this will create a PDF file for a student based on the provided ID and preview the report in the viewer. If you want to create PDF files for all the students, you will have to loop through all the IDs and export the files based on the same principle.

To use the above code, just replace the "Username" and the "Password" with the credentials of your database and the "Parametername" with the name that you used in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve your goal:

A. Create a report, which contains information about all the students, group the information by student and burst the report to pdfs. Bursting will generate a separate PDF file for each group ( student)

B. Create a report, which contains the information for a single student, create a list of students and run the report for each record in the list.

There are tools on the market that you can use to generate the PDF files.
I am using R-Tag (http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/ReportManager.aspx). It is not free , but comes with 30 days fully functional trial period, which will be more than enough for you to finish your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NameSpace
{
    class Program
    {
        struct student
        {
            public string stid;
            public string stname;
            public string stage;

        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] st = new student[4];
            int choice;
            string confirm;
            int count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Data");
            Console.WriteLine("1. ADD");
            Console.WriteLine("2. UPDATE");
            Console.WriteLine("3. DELETE");
            Console.WriteLine("4. SHOW");
            do
            {
                Console.Write("enter your choice(1-4):");
                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Add(st, count);
                        count++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Update(st);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Delete(st);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Show(st);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter b/w 1-4\n");
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write("Press Y or y to continue:");
                confirm = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            } while (confirm == "Y" || confirm == "y");
        }
        static void Add(student[] st, int count)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            st[count].stid = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
            st[count].stname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter student age: ");
            st[count].stage = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Show(student[] st)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (st[count].stid != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nStudent ID : " + st[count].stid);
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Name : " + st[count].stname);
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Age : " + st[count].stage);
                }
            }
        }
        static void Delete(student[] st)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            string studid = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (studid == st[count].stid)
                {
                    st[count].stid = null;
                    st[count].stname = null;
                    st[count].stage = null;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Update(student[] st)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            string studid = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (studid == st[count].stid)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
                    st[count].stname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter student age: ");
                    st[count].stage = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.